# Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows !=, <, <= , >, >=

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to make it so a field is updated so that the customers that had sales above 0 have the CustomerLevel at 'Level 1' but this is not working for me:

```
UPDATE Customers 
    SET CustomerLevel = 'Level 1' 
WHERE (
       (SELECT SUM(Sales.Subtotal)
        FROM Sales 
        JOIN Customers
        ON Customers.CustomerID = Sales.CustomerID
        GROUP BY Customers.CustomerID
       )
>=0)
```

Comment: What about the error don't you understand? It's quite specific.

Comment: Your query has `>=` but your description says "above 0" - so which is the actual desired update then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your subquery is returning a sales subtotal for **all** customer IDs (as you are referencing another instance of the `customers` table in the subquery), for every record of the `customers` table in the `UPDATE` query.

You should instead use a correlated subquery which references the `customerid` of the current record being updated, i.e.:

```
update customers c set c.customerlevel = 'level 1' 
where (select sum(s.subtotal) from sales s where s.customerid = c.customerid) >= 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Several ways to do this.  Speculating but this will probably have the best execution plan but check that.

```
UPDATE Customers 
    SET CustomerLevel = 'Level 1' 
FROM Customers AS c1
INNER JOIN
       (SELECT 
            SUM(Sales.Subtotal) AS sum2, 
            s2.CustomerID AS CustomerID2
        FROM Sales AS s2
        GROUP BY s2.CustomerID
       ) AS t2
ON t2.CustomerID = c1.CustomerID 
   AND t2.sum2 >=0
```